# Getting started with Radio design

Tags: rf, ham-radio, sdr

For a while now, I have been exploring many RF, communication protocol and radio etc. I am kind of looking for a way where i can implement the software stack for a particular open Radio. Means like implementation of WiFi, 802.15.4 like stack. I am not talking about usage of WiFi stack. I want to learn by building a stack similar to WiFi. In that case how do i get started and what RF modules can i use.

Comment: Open Radio is an [app](https://m.apkpure.com/open-radio/com.yuriy.openradio) building project. Do you instead mean software defined radio? There are many kits available on Amazon and depending on your current skill level you can choose the most suitable one.

Answer (score 4):

You'd not start by buying hardware – you'd start by

1. understanding *how* these devices work, then
2. implementing them in software, then
3. making your software fast enough to run in realtime, *then*
4. you consider buying devices.

Don't skip 1-3!

Re 1.: You will need a basis in signal theory; Oppenheim's "*discrete-time signal processing*" is your friend (and cheaply available in used form). Then you'll need a basis in communications technology. There's many books, but I guess with but a single book as signal theory background, you want something nice and manageable, "*Digital Communications, Fundamentals and Applications*", 2nd ed., by Sklar. Or you go for the [freely available](http://www.afidc.ethz.ch/A_Foundation_in_Digital_Communication/Home.html) "*A Foundation in Digital Communication*", by Amos Lapidoth.

Re 2. implementation in software: https://pysdr.org is a nice intro. Once you went through with that, learn with [GNU Radio](https://gnuradio.org).

Re 3.: well, this is software engineering, optimization, and I don't know what you'll have to optimize, so can't recommend anything just yet.

Re 4: you need a *software defined radio* device, like a Ettus USRP, or a HackRF, or a LimeSDR, or a BladeRF…

Answer (score 1):

RF software stacks are tough to write and test because the C programmer needs to know the meaning of every hardware register of the transceiver.

I would start with a simple 433/868/915 MHz transceiver that has a few registers and a few modulation schemes.

I would start with a star topology where (n-1) devices can't talk to each other but can only talk to a master node.

I would not use frequency hopping schemes.

Start with the basics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you suggest me any module with which i can start. I am a pure c programmer. I am unaware of rf modules which contains registers.

Comment: I used S2-LP transceivers made by ST. I bought 3 official transceiver boards STEVAL-FKI868V1 and 3 official main boards NUCLEO-L152RE. Than I started by studying and modifying the C examples.